# URl rewrite with nginx and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a large number of product id URL

```
domain.com/product.php?product_id=123&app_data=xyz123
```

My use case is to rewrite those URL to below format

**/product/productid/appdata**

I have written a rewrite rule.

```
rewrite ^/product/productid/(.*)        /product.php?product_id=$1&$query_string last;
```

But when I hit

```
domain.com/product.php?product_id=123412&app_data=cHJvZHVjdF9pZD0xODc2NTEmZGVmU2
```

It doesn't rewrite to

```
domain.com/product/productid/appdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting happens entirely on the server, it takes **A** to **B**, as in

```
rewrite A B
```

If A is `domain.com/product.php?product_id=123412&app_data=cHJvZHVjdF9pZD0xODc2NTEmZGVmU2`, then you're doing it *backwards*.

Try:

```
location / { 
  if ($query_string ~ "^product_id=([^&]+)&app_data=([^&\ ]+)") { 
    rewrite ^/product.php$ /product/%1/%2? redirect; 
  } 
} 

location /product { 
  rewrite ^/product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /product.php?product_id=$1&app_data=$2 break; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem..
if I access
**domain.com/product.php?product_id=123412&app_data=cHJvZHVjdF9pZD0xODc2NTEmZGVmU2**

i didn't redirect to **domain.com/product/productid/appdata**

but if I directly hit **domain.com/product/productid/appdata** i get the result but my css and image style gets broken.


and one more thing that I am not using any php framework. It's hardcoded self written code.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you want redirect or internal rewrite. First case:

```
location /product.php {
    rewrite 301 http://domain.com/product/$arg_product_id/$arg_app_data;
}
```

Second:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/product.php$ http://domain.com/product/$arg_product_id/$arg_app_data last;
}
```